# what is the difference between CONTENT_FILTER_URI and CONTENT_URI?

Tags: android

what are the difference between these two **Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI** and 
**Contacts.CONTENT_URI** in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking online?
It's explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Comment: I'm trying to make my own `ContentProvider` and I want to get a filtered query result, following [an example of using the LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html), and I can't seem to tell what the difference between the `CONTENT_FILTER_URI` and the `CONTENT_URI` is. I understand the filter uri is supposed to be optimized for searching for specific phone numbers but I don't understand if it's important and what exactly it does. I've tried calling a lot of the Uri's methods but none revealed the Uri string used. Could you help?

Comment: I feel this answer would be much more helpful if there was an example or even an addition on top of the trivial documentation link.